# GGplot2 facet_wrap() with scaling for each variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have a dataframe `data` with 9 predictor variables and one indicator variable `ind` with values from 0 to 3. I need to make histograms for all of the variables given a value of `ind`. I've already wrote some code; having no better idea I just divided my dataset into 4 disjoint subsets.

```
data_no0 <- data[data$ind == 0, -1]
data_no1 <- data[data$ind == 1, -1]
data_no2 <- data[data$ind == 2, -1]
data_no3 <- data[data$ind == 3, -1]

ggplot(gather(data_no1), aes(value)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 6) + 
  facet_wrap(~key, scales = 'free_x')
```

[image]

What's more I want to be able to **compare histograms** for different values of `ind` so I would like to fix min and max values of x to be (i.e for the first variable) `min(data$avg_f0env_sma0)` and `max(data$avg_f0env_sma)`, respectively.

I've tried to do it in that way:

```
scales_x <- list(
  'avg_jitterlocal_sma' 
  = scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min(data$avg_jitterlocal_sma), max(data$avg_jitterlocal_sma))),
  'avg_jitterddp_sma' 
  = scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min(data$avg_jitterddp_sma), max(data$avg_jitterddp_sma))),
  'avg_shimmerlocal_sma' 
  = scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min(data$avg_shimmerlocal_sma), max(data$avg_shimmerlocal_sma))),
  'avgx_pcm_fftmag_spectralflux_sma' 
  = scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min(data$avg_pcm_fftmag_spectralflux_sma), max(data$avg_pcm_fftmag_spectralflux_sma))),
  'avg_pcm_fftmag_spectralcentroid_sma' 
  = scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min(data$avg_pcm_fftmag_spectralcentroid_sma), max(data$avg_pcm_fftmag_spectralcentroid_sma))),
  'avg_pcm_fftmag_spectralharmonicity_sma_compare' 
  = scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min(data$avg_pcm_fftmag_spectralharmonicity_sma_compare), max(data$avg_pcm_fftmag_spectralharmonicity_sma_compare))),
  'avg_f0final_sma' 
  = scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min(data$avg_f0final_sma), max(data$avg_f0final_sma))),
  'avg_f0env_sma' 
  = scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min(data$avg_f0env_sma), max(data$avg_f0env_sma))),
  'avg_loudness_sma3' 
  = scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min(data$avg_loudness_sma3), max(data$avg_loudness_sma3)))
)

ggplot(gather(data_no0), aes(value)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 6) + 
  facet_wrap(~key, scales = list(x = scales_x))
```

But it doesn't work. I've also read about `facet_grid_sc()`, but there's also a problem with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like your dataset could use some [tidying](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html), but data wrangling principles aside, it seems that you are looking to control the scales individually for each facet - am I correct?

The `lemon` package contains some useful functions including `facet_rep_wrap()` and `facet_rep_grid()`.  One useful feature of these functions is to allow for each facet to have a differently scaled y or x axis.  Here's an example with the `diamonds` dataset.

Histograms of price according to cut with `facet_wrap()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lemon)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=price, fill=cut)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_wrap(~cut)
```

[image]

And here's the same plot using `lemon::facet_rep_wrap()` with a free y scale:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=price, fill=cut)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_rep_wrap(~cut, scales="free")
```

[image]